# XSL transformation with link in variable name

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSL which I render into my HTML:

```
<xsl:for-each select="user"> 
<xsl:variable name="exampleurl"> 
<xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:when test="objecttype='2'">
         Check this out: 
         <strong><a class="link" href="http://www.example.com/beinspired">Inspiration</a></strong>.
     </xsl:when> 
</xsl:choose> 
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:value-of select="$exampleurl" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, when I print the variable $exampleurl only the text "Check this out: Inspiration." is printed. But the word "Inspiration" is not a clickable URL like I would want.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

value-of creates a text node, you want

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$exampleurl" />
```

(or of course in this case you don't need a variable at all, but I assume that's just the small example?

Comment: Correct, this was just a small example. Your answer did the trick. Thank you.